# If the TVA exists outside of time, why are there still nexus events?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, timeline, loki-2021, time-variance-authority

In the new Loki TV show, we see the TVA having to deal with nexus events from "time to time" (no pun intended). However, we are also made aware that the TVA exists outside of what we would consider the normal flow of time. If this is the case, then why has the TVA not already seen and dealt with all the possible nexus events that would have occurred?

One possible answer that we got was when Mobius and Loki were talking in the second episode of the series - that the Time Keepers were working on writing the future of the sacred timeline, and when they finish, there would be no more nexus events to deal with. However, assuming nexus events are caused solely by beings/people in the sacred timeline itself, doesn't this mean that there should really only be nexus events in close temporal proximity to the "new stuff" that the Time Keepers are "writing" into the sacred timeline?

It just seems to me like, if the TVA truly exists outside of our regular flow of time, then all possible past, present, and future occurrences (up to the point where the Time Keepers have written, which is clearly past the present day, since Loki and Mobius casually read up on disasters in the 2050's) should have "already happened" for the TVA, and thus, their field agents should not have to "wait" for said nexus events to occur for them to go in and prune them. What am I missing?

Comment: "if the TVA truly exists outside of our regular flow of time, then all possible past, present, and future occurrences... should have "already happened" for the TVA" — should they? Is that how time works in real world?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One important thing to keep in mind is that a creator simply cannot make a story that exists out of time.

For instance, take a look at this scene from the trailer:

> MOBIUS: Loki, I’ve studied every moment of your entire life. You’ve literally stabbed people in the back, like, 50 times.
>
> LOKI: Well, I'll never do it again!

Loki says his line *AFTER* Mobius says his. Mobius says his *BEFORE* Loki.

The concepts of before and after only make sense when you have some kind of timeline.

So based on this, for the series to make sense to the audience, there has to be some kind of "Supreme Timeline" where all the events happen chronologically. We can't judge the relative speeds of time in the so-called "Supreme Timeline" and the Sacred Timeline. But it's a reasonable assumption that if a nexus event occurs at some instance in the Sacred Timeline, it only occurs *AFTER* the responsible person (say Sylvie) causes it, with respect to the "Supreme Timeline".

Finally, Mobius himself says:

> Time passes differently in the TVA.

Which implies that time **does** pass in the TVA, it's just separate from the regular timeline (the Sacred Timeline) that exists in the rest of the universe.

It doesn't imply that time doesn't pass in the TVA at all. So nexus events can certainly happen, and only after (with respect to the "Supreme Timeline") the responsible person causes the nexus event.

Answer (score 0):

**Because there are infinite nexus events.**

It doesn't really matter how time works in the TVA headquarter. As time is infinite in the sacred timeline, there is also the possibility of infinite nexus events.

There is always more work to do.