# What are the implications of the statue at the end of Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

***Note: Contains spoilers for all episodes of Loki.***

At the end of *Loki* 1x6, Loki looks out into the TVA to see a statue of

> He Who Remains (presumably Kang the Conqueror) as the Timekeeper.

What are the implications of this? If He Who Remains has taken over the TVA already, does that mean that the multiverse has already been resolved? Does it mean that Loki has come to a different TVA? I know we can't have canon answers to this but I'm curious as to whether this will have impact on *Spider-Man: No Way Home* and *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*.

Comment: Did you watch the final dialogue between Mobius and Loki when Loki appears back at the TVA after the Kang encounter?

Comment: Yes, in which Mobius had no memory of Loki and was either a different variant or the same variant under a memory wipe (such things seem to be possible by the TVA)

Comment: not "presumably" fwiw. Check out the latest episode of the behind the scenes "Assembled" - it's confirmed by production staff

Comment: [The answers to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251669/58193) seem relevant here.

Comment: note for anyone clicking the above link from @TheLethalCarrot, there be potential spoilers there. In that, things marked as spoilers in this question and answer thread are not marked as such over there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The revelation that

> Agent Mobius doesn't recognize Loki at all

during the final dialog, along with seeing the statue of

> Kang instead of the Timekeepers

Makes it clear that Loki has somehow made it to an alternate reality.

The statue depicts, specifically,

> Kang the Conqueror

based on the outfit depicted on said statue. It's also somewhat confirmed in [this Marvel.com article](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/loki-he-who-remains-citadel-end-of-time-kang-statue) if you look at the tags and intuit that the next instance of this character that we see (and arguably the main one the TV show will be dealing with will be that person in their traditional nom de guerre of) will be

> Kang the Conqueror.

Comment: Check out the latest episode of the behind the scenes "Assembled" - the character is confirmed by production staff